# What to look for when using a 3rd party Email Enrichment Service - to secure our emails?

Tags: spf, dkim

Our marketing team wants to use a 3rd party Email Enrichment Service.

I want to try and tackle this, as I don't like the idea that my mail will go through a certified service and exposed.

I know about SPF and DKIM - both are available to set on the 3rd party server.

What should I look for with the 3rd party company, in order that our emails will stay secure?
And not exposed?

Comment: Its email.  Its already exposed the moment it leaves your server.  If anything I would give you a dozen reasons TO let a third party handle bulk mailings.  What are you afraid of when you say its exposed?

Comment: As long as they send mail from a dedicated (sub-) domain and not your primary, why not?  E.g. give your marketing `@campaigns.example.com` or `@example-campaigns.com` and not `campaigns@example.com`.

Comment: @HBruijn thank for the tip. I think of exposing email / sensitive data etc. CEO emails, etc..

Answer (score 3):

**Don't associate your regular email domain with e-mail campaigns**

However well maintained and legitimate the distribution lists, any sufficiently large mailing may be classified by sufficient people and/or systems as spam that it can result in blacklisting you regular e-mail.

You don't want to deal with either sending large volumes of mail using your regular infrastructure, interfering with regular mail traffic, nor with large numbers of bounces.

So instruct your marketing people they can't use an `@example.com` email address for their campaigns, nor the regular mail servers.

**Seperate marketing domain**

Create either a subdomain e.g. `campaigns.example.com` or register a new domain `example-campaigns.com` and set up the MX records and such according to the specs of your third party.

Don't set up a host for `campaigns.example.com` in the same subnet of your regular smtp gateway if you can avoid it.

Leave the third party in control of the whole process of sending the campaigns and its not your problem to resolve blacklisting etc.